# How can I create a second instance of my application?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want a new instance of my app to be created for every filepath handed to it via command-line args at startup.

Right now I have this in my main window's constructor:

```
if (args.Length > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
            {
                string arg = args[i];

                if (File.Exists(arg))
                {
                    if (i > 0)
                        Process.Start(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, arg);
                    else
                        OpenFile(arg);
                }
            }
        }
```

But, right now my program seems to create new instances of itself until my computer runs our of memory. Do you see what's wrong?

**--Edit--**

The Args come from an override of the Appplication.OnStartup Event.

Comment: What happens if you step through it in the debugger?

Comment: It gets to Process.Start(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, arg); and then keeps spawning more and more instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to

```
Process.Start(typeof(MainWindow).Assembly.Location, "\"" + arg + "\"");
```

(With quotes around the argument)

If arg came from a quoted path with spaces, passing it to `Process.Start` will pass the unquoted value as two arguments.  You need to put quotes around it to ensure that you only get one argument.

Changing the first parameter will make it shorter and a little faster, but won't vchange the behavior.

Comment: I suspect that this isn't your immediate problem, but it's certainly a bug you should fix.

Comment: Thank you! If only I had seen this when you posted it yesterday. I spent at least an hour wondering wtf was wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the check for `if (args.Length > 0)`, because the for-loop will take care of that.  If you need to skip arg 0 (as suggested by SLaks), just change the for-loop to `int i = 1`.

Note that if you always pass an argument to a sub-process, and your check is based on their being *any* arguments, you will infinitely recurse.

So this line should change:

```
if (i > 0)
    // Spawn new process, passing the argument
```

To:

```
if (i > 1)
    // Spawn new process, passing the argument
```

Also, this code is fairly confusing, as has been proven by the answers here.  Here is much simpler code:

```
foreach (string arg in args.Skip(2)) // Just Skip(1) if it turns out args[0] != this.exe
    Process.Start(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, arg);

if (args.Length > 1) // > 0 if it turns out args[0] != this.exe
    OpenFile(args[1]);
```

Comment: No, it won't.   He's already checking for `i > 0`.  Also, this will prevent it from actually opening the file.

Comment: You're right that after accounting for the first arg, he'll need to check whether `i > 1`.

Comment: We're both wrong. `StartupEventArgs.Args` doesn't include the app name.  (I checked the docs and the source)

Answer (score 1):

Answer: I'm an idiot.

For testing purposes I hard-coded some args, which ever new instance then spawned with.

Feel free to point and laugh or throw eggs at me through your computer screen.

Comment: You should still fix the unrelated bug in my (new) answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to allow all of the processing to run concurrently, why not just use threads?

```
foreach (var i in args) {
    new Thread(delegate {
        try { OpenFile(i); }
        catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine("Error processing file {0}: {1}",
                                                i, e.ToString()); }
    }).Start();
}
```

Comment: Multiple UI threads are a bad idea.  Also, this is the window's constructor; he'd need to call `new Application().Run(new MainWindow(...))`

Comment: Ah, missed the part of the question specifying that it was a GUI app.

Comment: He might be able to do hack this up if he used appdomains for each UI, but it would probably be fairly buggy.  A better idea would be to refactor the app to support multiple files/multiple windows.